Azure Key vault creation and configuration using script
I'm new to the Azure Key vault automation. I know its possible to create/automate the AKV creation using ARM template or Terraform or some other script. I have a requirement to create, configure and store the secrets in the Key vault.
Step1: Create a Key vault in a particular subscription and resource group.
Step2: Automatically read the password from a excel file and put the password as secrets in Key Vault.

Step3: Configure the Key vault in such that Apps can fetch the "secrets" from the key Vault.


Azure Key vault creation and configuration using script

Here is the Python code to fulfil the following requirements:

Create a resource group.
Create a Azure key vault with RBAC.
Enable a system-assigned managed identity for the existing web app.
Assign the Secret User role to the web app's identity.
Read data from an Excel file.
Create secrets in the Key Vault with the same values as those in the Excel file (for example, the Excel file name represents the secret name, and the password represents the secret value).


Note: Make sure to keep the Excel file in the same directory.

requirements.txt
    openpyxl
    azure-identity
    azure-mgmt-keyvault
    azure-mgmt-resource
    azure-mgmt-authorization
    azure-mgmt-web
    azure-keyvault-secrets

Install the module using below cmdlet
pip install -r requirements.txt

Python code:
import openpyxl
import uuid
import os 
import time
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.keyvault import KeyVaultManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.keyvault.models import VaultCreateOrUpdateParameters, Sku, SkuName
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.web import WebSiteManagementClient
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.mgmt.authorization.models import RoleAssignmentCreateParameters
import subprocess

# Configuration
SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "SUB_ID"
RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME = "webapprgtestprod"
LOCATION = "East US"
KEY_VAULT_NAME = "venkatkeyvaultheja"
WEB_APP_NAME = "venkatwebapp"
WEB_APP_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME = "web-app-RG"

# Authenticate
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
keyvault_client = KeyVaultManagementClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
auth_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
web_client = WebSiteManagementClient(credential, SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

# Step 1: Ensure Resource Group Exists
print("Checking if Resource Group exists...")
try:
    resource_group = resource_client.resource_groups.get(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME)
    print(f"Resource Group exists: {RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}")
except Exception:
    print("Creating Resource Group...")
    resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, {'location': LOCATION})
    print(f"Resource Group created: {RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}")

# Step 2: Create or Retrieve Key Vault
try:
    keyvault = keyvault_client.vaults.get(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, KEY_VAULT_NAME)
    key_vault_url = keyvault.properties.vault_uri
    print(f"Key Vault exists: {key_vault_url}")
except Exception:
    print("Creating Key Vault...")
    key_vault_parameters = VaultCreateOrUpdateParameters(
        location=LOCATION,
        properties={
            "sku": Sku(name=SkuName.premium),
            "tenant_id": "Tenat_ID",
            "access_policies": [],
        },
    )
    keyvault = keyvault_client.vaults.begin_create_or_update(
        RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, KEY_VAULT_NAME, key_vault_parameters
    ).result()
    key_vault_url = keyvault.properties.vault_uri
    print(f"Key Vault created: {key_vault_url}")

# Step 3: Enable System-Assigned Identity for Web App
print("Enabling system-assigned identity for Web App...")
web_app = web_client.web_apps.get(WEB_APP_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, WEB_APP_NAME)
web_app.identity = {"type": "SystemAssigned"}
web_client.web_apps.begin_create_or_update(WEB_APP_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, WEB_APP_NAME, web_app)

# Verify identity is enabled
for _ in range(12):  # Retry for up to 60 seconds
    web_app = web_client.web_apps.get(WEB_APP_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, WEB_APP_NAME)
    principal_id = web_app.identity.principal_id
    if principal_id:
        print(f"System-assigned identity enabled. Principal ID: {principal_id}")
        break
    time.sleep(5)
else:
    raise Exception("Failed to enable system-assigned identity for Web App.")

# Step 4: Assign "Key Vault Secrets User" Role
print("Assigning 'Key Vault Secrets User' role...")
key_vault_resource_id = keyvault.id

role_definition_id = next(
    (role.id for role in auth_client.role_definitions.list(
        scope=key_vault_resource_id,
        filter="roleName eq 'Key Vault Secrets User'"
    )), None
)

if role_definition_id:
    existing_assignments = list(auth_client.role_assignments.list_for_scope(key_vault_resource_id))
    if not any(
        ra.principal_id == principal_id and ra.role_definition_id == role_definition_id
        for ra in existing_assignments
    ):
        role_assignment_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
        auth_client.role_assignments.create(
            scope=key_vault_resource_id,
            role_assignment_name=role_assignment_name,
            parameters=RoleAssignmentCreateParameters(
                principal_id=principal_id,
                role_definition_id=role_definition_id,
                principal_type="ServicePrincipal",
            ),
        )
        print("'Key Vault Secrets User' role assigned successfully.")
    else:
        print("'Key Vault Secrets User' role already assigned.")
else:
    print("Role definition for 'Key Vault Secrets User' not found.")

# Step 5: Read from Excel and Create Secrets
print("Creating secrets in Key Vault...")
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=key_vault_url, credential=credential)

file_path = r'Appdata.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = wb.active

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=5):  # Skip headers
    secret_name = row[0].value
    secret_value = row[4].value
    if secret_name and secret_value:
        secret_client.set_secret(secret_name, secret_value)
        print(f"Secret '{secret_name}' created.")
    else:
        print(f"Skipping row {row[0].row}: Missing secret name or value.")
        
print("All the processes have been completed successfully.")


Output

Secrets created with the same values as in the Excel file.


Configure the Key vault in such that Apps can fetch the "secrets" from the key Vault.

You can enable the system-assigned managed identity on the web app and assign a role to the identity in the Key Vault, so that the web app can access and fetch secrets from the Key Vault.

Key vault Creation

